# Detect if user can't view article in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

[Joomla 2.5]

I just made every article on my Joomla website only viewable by registered users.

**What works:** When I am not logged in and go to one of the articles, I see nothing.

**What I'd like:** Some way to display a message when the article is being hidden from the non-registered (i.e. public) individual?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an extention like [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/content-restriction/24225)?

Answer (score 1):

Turn Show UnAuthorised on. This will display whatever you put before the readmore and give a link to the login page.